# GSON serialize multiple properties to sub object

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I've been experimenting with Retrofit and GSON in my project and came across an unusual case where I'm trying to convert two properties from JSON into a sub object using GSON on Android.

Example JSON:

```
{
  "cat1_id": "1111",
  "cat1_name": "First Category",
  "cat2_id": "2222",
  "cat2_name": "Second Category",
}
```

Following typical examples, it seems like one would normally create a class like this.

```
public class InventoryItem {

     private int    cat1_id;
     private String cat1_name;
     private int    cat2_id;
     private String cat2_id;

}
```

However, I would rather do something like this this.

```
public class InventoryItem {

    private Category category1;
    private Category category2;
}

public class Category {
    private int    id;
    private String name;
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with GSON? I've been considering just creating a POJO that Retrofit can use as a response, then using a for loop to convert it to the format I like better. But that seems like it defeats the entire purpose of GSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest two approaches.

### Let a class act as a bridge builder

Just redefine your initial `InventoryItem` class so that it acts as a builder for an `InventoryItemBuilder`.

```
class InventoryItemBuilder {
    @SerializedName("cat1_id")   private int    catOneId;
    @SerializedName("cat1_name") private String catOneName;
    @SerializedName("cat2_id")   private int    catTwoId;
    @SerializedName("cat2_name") private String catTwoName;

    public InventoryItem buildInventoryItem() {
        Category c1 = new Category(catOneId, catOneName);
        Category c2 = new Category(catTwoId, catTwoName);
        return new InventoryItem(c1, c2);
    }
}
```

Then you'll just need to call the `buildInventoryItem()` method after you deserialize the JSON into an `ItemHolder` instance:

```
//InventoryItem{category1=Category{id=1111, name='First Category'}, category2=Category{id=2222, name='Second Category'}}
InventoryItem inventoryItem = new Gson().fromJson(json, InventoryItemBuilder.class).buildInventoryItem();
```

### Implement a custom deserializer

Just tell the parser how you want to deserialize the JSON entity you described:

```
class InventoryItemDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<InventoryItem> {
    @Override
    public InventoryItem deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        Category c1 = new Category(jObject.get("cat1_id").getAsInt(), jObject.get("cat1_name").getAsString());
        Category c2 = new Category(jObject.get("cat2_id").getAsInt(), jObject.get("cat2_name").getAsString());
        return new InventoryItem(c1, c2);
    }
}
```

then register it in the parser:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(InventoryItem.class, new InventoryItemDeserializer()).create();
```

and use it:

```
InventoryItem inventoryItem = gson.fromJson(json, InventoryItem.class);
```

This yields the same output as before. Of course the deserializer could be a bit less specific (by iterating over the entry set of the object for instance). This should give you some insights.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: If I use the custom deserializer, will I have to manually tell it how to do everything? Or can I just specify the categories. (I, of course, have other fields to worry about.)

Comment: @Hackmodford I'm not sure I get what you really mean. But yes you can specify what you want to deserialize when the JSON will represent an `InventoryItem`. Depending on the structure, you can more or less easily skip what you want to keep or not.

Comment: I wanted Gson to do most everything automatically, and only custom deserialize the category information. I think I have a solution. (See my answer) Do you have any comments about that?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here is an example of a solution that I am testing.

```
public class InventoryItem {

    @SerializedName("AUTO")     private int mPersistentId;
    @SerializedName("ID")       private String mItemId;
    @SerializedName("BARCODE")  private String mBarcode;
    @SerializedName("ALIAS")    private String mAlias;
    @SerializedName("ALIAS2")   private String mAlias2;
    @SerializedName("NAME")     private String mDescription;

    private Category mCategory;
    private Category mSubCategory;
    private Category mFinalCategory;
}
```

This is my custom deserializer

```
public class InventoryItemDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<InventoryItem> {

    private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().create();

    @Override
    public InventoryItem deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonObject jObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        InventoryItem item = GSON.fromJson(json, InventoryItem.class);

        item.setCategory(new Category(jObject.get("cat1_id").getAsInt(), jObject.get("cat1_name").getAsString()));
        item.setSubCategory(new Category(jObject.get("cat2_id").getAsInt(), jObject.get("cat2_name").getAsString()));
        item.setFinalCategory(new Category(jObject.get("cat3_id").getAsInt(), jObject.get("cat3_name").getAsString()));

        return item;
    }
}
```